# Get backreference name-based regex from index-based regex

Tags: c#, regex, backreference

I have this regex string:

```
^(\()?\d+(?(1)\))$
```

It will match following strings:

```
123
(1234)
1
(33)
```

But will not match following strings:

```
(123
123)
```

I would like to convert the index-based regex to name-based regex, but following regex seem don't work:

```
^(?<bracket>\()?\d+(?(\k<bracket>)\))$
```

What is equivalent name-based regex for the first regex string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an if clause, not a backreference. - `\k` is a backreference. The syntax to test for a previously named subpattern is

```
(?(<bracket>)
```

So, try:

```
^(?<bracket>\()?\d+(?(<bracket>)\))$
```

https://regex101.com/r/Oy9q1H/1

Comment: I checked again and see that in c# you need to remove `<` and `>` characters in the if condition to make it work. The final regex is `^(?<bracket>\()?\d+(?(bracket)\))$`

Comment: Regex101 does not support .NET regex syntax. It can only show how a regex might work, but cannot be used as a proof the regex will work in the target environment.

Answer (score 2):

To test if a named group stack is not empty, you should use the name itself inside parentherses:

```
^(?<bracket>\()?\d+(?(bracket)\))$
                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3Cbracket%3E%5C%28%29%3F%5Cd%2B%28%3F%28bracket%29%5C%29%29%5Cr%3F%24&i=123%0D%0A%281234%29%0D%0A1%0D%0A%2833%29%0D%0ABut%20will%20not%20match%20following%20strings%3A%0D%0A%0D%0A%28123%0D%0A123%29&o=m)

See the [Conditional Matching Based on a Valid Captured Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/alternation-constructs-in-regular-expressions#conditional-matching-based-on-a-valid-captured-group):

> This language element attempts to match one of two patterns depending on whether it has matched a specified capturing group. Its syntax is:
>
> `(?( name ) yes | no )`
>
> or
>
> `(?( number ) yes | no )`
>
> where *name* is the name and *number* is the number of a capturing group, *yes* is the expression to match if *name* or *number* has a match, and no is the optional expression to match if it does not.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/7HFSHW):

```
var strs = new List<string> { "123", "(1234)", "1", "(33)", "(123", "123)"};
var rx = new Regex(@"^(?<bracket>\()?\d+(?(bracket)\))$");
    foreach (var s in strs)
        Console.WriteLine($"{s} => {rx.IsMatch(s)}");
```

Output:

```
123 => True
(1234) => True
1 => True
(33) => True
(123 => False
123) => False
```